# Error while trying to create kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka

When trying to create kafka topics in local, getting the below error.

```
aakarshit@VYMO-IT-LPT-712 Cellar % kafka-topics --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 10 --topic workflow
Error: VM option 'UseG1GC' is experimental and must be enabled via -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: Upgrade your Java to 11 or 17

Answer (score 1):

First we need to find the place where kafka is getting loaded. For this go to

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/kafka/3.4.0/bin/kafka-topics.
```

Then find the path where kafka is getting exexcuted. In my case it was this

```
 exec "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/kafka/3.4.0/libexec/bin/kafka-topics.sh"
```

We need to change the following file content.

```
1. Go to this /opt/homebrew/Cellar/kafka/3.4.0/libexec/bin/kafka-run-class.sh
2. Find the -XX:+UseG1GC and delete the word.
```

**NOTE:** Stop kafka and zookeeper before doing the kafka-run-class.sh and then after saving the changes.

Comment: `-XX:+UseG1GC ` works fine and doesn't need removed

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please check the above solution is when you are facing the above mentioned error in the question. If there is no error coming then obviously no need to remove :)

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments above, I think you should double check what Java version you've installed, not modify a script. Kafka doesn't support all Java versions